# converting parallels pvm files to virtualbox readable

Tags: hard-drive, virtualbox, parallels

I am having issues with parallels, and so I decided to go forth with migrating my stuff to virtualbox, since it's much better, it has always worked.

I've googled ways to convert a pvm file to hdd, however, once I finish the process I still end up with something that won't boot.  For instance, these are the steps I follow to get the resulting solution:

1. make required backups on my mac, being used as the vm-host
   (parallels 15.1.4)
2. uninstall parallels tools from within the vm-guest os (windows 10 pro)
3. go to the given .pvm file, click "show package contents", and find the .hdd file listed inside
4. click on the .hdd file, and once more select "show package contents" to reveal yet another hidden gem that is extension .hds
5. copy the .hds file somewhere accessible by virtualbox (inside a directory for the vm you create), and rename it .hdd
6. voila, it should work?

I've tried this method also using a command line tool to convert something (not really), but all it did was inflate the 10gb file into 120gb, and still remained un-bootable. :(

any ideas? :)

Comment: Same problem here. "No boot device found"